# Visual Studio Professional 2015 Test Coverage

Tags: visual-studio-2015, code-coverage, opencover

I'm trying to configure [opencover](https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover) with Visual Studio 2015 Professional edition.

I use Visual Studio In Build MS Test tool for Unit testing.

I have a few challenges on this ,

1.First I have installed opencover Version 4.6.519

2. Then [report generator](https://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiyiovm0ffKAhVCiCwKHUm4A3gQFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Freportgenerator.codeplex.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNG-Mq7S1xeuxuc_2Upi5ZWLP7e9qw&sig2=DsZpAHgdNMW1aXL4-WuZNg&bvm=bv.114195076,d.bGg) Version 2.4.3.0

First challenge that I'm facing is getting the Test Result out put from the visual studio. I'm running on default test configuration.

Though it creates Test Result folder , I do not see any test result file available.

Then I tried to install OpenCover UI extension available [here](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6950a046-8919-4935-8542-c6f37956f688).

Once I installed I'm getting following error ,

[image]

> An Exception occured , Could Not Fine a part of the path
>   C:\Users\MyUserAccount\Desktop\MyApp\123244-43434-343434....\TestResults
>
> Please refer to out come Window For More Details.

When I check the outcome window this is the out put

Error: None of the provided test containers match the Platform Architecture and .Net Framework settings for the test run. Platform: X86  .Net Framework: Framework45. Go to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=330428 for more details on managing these settings.

> Could not find a part of the path
>   'C:\Users\vsuvinith\Desktop\RFS\OpenCover\f83ba963-16d1-450d-915b-6920d402c961\TestResults'.
>   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.CommonInit()    at
>   System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String
>   originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption,
>   SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost)    at
>   System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(String path, String searchPattern)    at
>   OpenCover.UI.Processors.MSTestExecutor.UpdateTestResultsFile()    at
>   OpenCover.UI.Processors.MSTestExecutor.ReadTestResults()    at
>   OpenCover.UI.Processors.TestExecutor.Execute()    at
>   OpenCover.UI.Commands.ExecuteSelectedTestsCommand.b__1()

Other Things that might help.

- Build is in X64
- Running on Windows 7 Enterprise Edition.
- Running on default configuration , no configuration has done.

can someone help me on getting this resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Viduru.
Are you sure, that you set executables correctly?
In the beginning OpenCover will ask you to find executables.
This is a **OpenCover.Console.exe** file.
You can get it in *%localappdata%\Apps\OpenCover* after the installing .msi-file from https://github.com/opencover/opencover/releases ([opencover.4.6.519.msi](https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover/releases/download/4.6.519/opencover.4.6.519.msi))

Comment: I have exactly the same error. I installed the same version of the msi that you mention. There don't appear to be any other configuration settings.